# How to change signing on completed Xcode project

Tags: xcode, profile, signing, apple-developer

I recently completed a project on Xcode 10 using my name and apple developer account. Now that it is done I began the process of transferring it to appstoreconnect so I could beta test with TestFlight. I found that you must be 18 to upload an app so I bought a developers account with my Mom's apple ID so I could publish my work through her. The problem I'm having now is I cannot change the signing on the account from my "Team" to hers. When I switch it to her's, I get a error saying "No profiles for 'com.xxxxx.xxxxx' were found". I guess my question then is how do I create a new provisional profile and link it to this project. Thanks for any help!

I've tried changing the bundle ID to one that exists in the appstoreconnect linked to an app I created for this project.

Comment: You can’t do anything with a team you’re not a member of. She needs to put you on her team.  Take a look at the Roles on Teams that Apple defines. https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: You need to be App Manager or Admin.

Comment: Oh and this is going to cost another $100